# Reactjs sorting of imported colours

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a file `colors.js` that exports a number of colors, some true hex code colors and some semantic proxy colors:

```
// True colors
export const BLACK = '#000000';
export const WHITE = "#FFFFFF";

// Semantic Proxy Colors
export const HOME_PAGE = WHITE;
export const DARK_STYLE = BLACK;
```

I then import all of the exported colors in a Component and map over them to produce a color palette for a style guide. I'm wanting to have two sections, one for True Colors and the other for Semantic Colors.

Currently (see code below) when I map over them, I get both True and Semantic colors. I'm wanting a way to look over the true colors and store them in a data structure, then look at each Semantic color and check whether the value corresponds to a key of a True color.

```
import * as Color from './colors';
...
render() {
    let colorsMap = Object.keys(Color);
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Colour Palette</h2>
            <div>
                {colorsMap.map((color) => <Swatch key={color} name={color} />)}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Swatch is a lightweight component that displays a div with the background color it receives from the `color` prop.

Comment: use regex to distinguish colors?

Comment: Export two objects instead: one with true colors and one with semantic colors.

Comment: 1. Export two/one object. 2. Use naming to distinguish hex colors `CLR_BLACK`.